# SOAPUI and Microsoft test management

Tags: mtm, soapui, api-testing

We are currently using SOAPUI to test SOAP and Restful API's. We then test our interfaces using Selenium automation tests. Where we are unable to automate or there is no value we test manually.

We are now looking to manage all tests via `Microsoft Test Manager`, however, cannot find how to integrate `SOAPUI`. So, the tests reside and report back to Microsoft Test Management.

Has anyone had an experience of:

1. Incorporating SOAPUI with Microsoft test manager
2. SOAPUI and other test management tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you find below resources helpful:

Here is the `SoapUI` [Documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/73372/) reference for the same.

> Microsoft Visual Studio includes tools and technologies for all members of software development teams: project architects, developers, managers and, of course, testers. TestComplete can integrate with these tools giving your Quality Assurance team the ability to --
>
> Run unit tests created with Visual Studio as part of your TestComplete projects.
>
> Run TestComplete tests directly from your MSBuild projects.
>
> Integrate TestComplete tests into your Visual Studio test projects and include them in your application's lifecycle managed by Visual Studio and Team Foundation tools:
>
> - Run TestComplete tests locally in Visual Studio.
> - Run TestComplete tests remotely in Visual Studio by using test controllers and test agents.
> - Plan and manage your TestComplete tests by using Microsoft Test Manager.
> - Run TestComplete tests as build verification tests (after Team Foundation Build builds your application).
>
> In other words, you can mix tests created in both products and make your testing flexible and powerful.
>
> TestComplete 11 can integrate with the following versions of Microsoft Visual Studio:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise and Professional editions).
> - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - 2013 (Ultimate, Premium, and Professional editions).
>
> Note for Windows 10, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 users: Currently, TestComplete needs specific preparations to be able to work via COM on Windows 10, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012. Since Visual Studio integration uses TestComplete COM interfaces, you may need to change the privileges of your application or TestComplete in order to be able to run tests. For detailed information on the needed preparations, see the Using TestComplete COM Interfaces on Windows 8 and Later Operating Systems section of the [Working With TestComplete via COM](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75758/#Manifest) - Overview topic.
>   In This Section
>
> [Running Unit Tests Created With Visual Studio in TestComplete Projects](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/67897/) 
>   Describes how you can run Visual Studio unit tests from TestComplete projects.
>
> [Running TestComplete Tests From MSBuild Projects](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75341/) 
>   Explains how to integrate TestComplete projects into MSBuild projects.
>
> [Integration With Visual Studio Application Lifecycle Management](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/71350/) 
>   Contains information on how to include TestComplete tests in your application's lifecycle managed by Visual Studio and Team Foundation tools.
>
> See also
>
> [Teamwork and Integration Into QA Process](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/71012/)

Here you can find a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEqihTq1FKg) for the same